# upload file to server via rdc in command line

Tags: upload, command-line-interface, remote-desktop

I have access to server only via RDC, and I was wondering if is it possible to upload file to it via command line? I've got application that only can be run on the server, and modyfing some files and send it to server via typical RDC client is to slow. So maybe I could do this via command line to make this faster?

Comment: Robocopy or XCopy will not work?

Comment: @Kane: It sounds like they don't have arbitrary IP connectivity to the server, but rather can only use the Remote Desktop protocol / client.

Answer (score 0):

If the Remote Desktop file sharing functionality (aka the File System Virtual Channel) isn't working fast enough for you your best hope is going to be find some other protocol to transfer the files via. Whether or not you're using a command-line tool is really irrelevant to the speed.

Assuming the remote server isn't prevented from doing so by firewall rules you might consider hosting a server on the Internet that you can transfer files to / from using a protocol like WebDAV or secure copy (SCP). If you're not permitted to make outbound requests from the server at all, though, you're probably out of luck. I'd talk to the administrator and see if you can work out an agreeable solution.